# openfire smack sending packet 404 error means?

Tags: java, openfire

when sending packet to openfire using Smack, i get error  remote-server-not-found(404)  . Can anyone please explain what does thet error means? it mean fail to connect to server or the packet has problem?

```
        PacketFilter responseFilter = new PacketIDFilter(packet.getPacketID());
        PacketCollector response = connection.createPacketCollector(responseFilter);

        connection.sendPacket(packet);



        // Wait up to a certain number of seconds for a reply.
        Packet result = response.nextResult(timeout);



        // Stop queuing results
        response.cancel();



        if (result == null) {
            throw new XMPPException("No response from server.");
        }
        else if (result.getError() != null) {  

            System.out.println("error:"+result.getError());   //i get error here.... 404
            throw new XMPPException(result.getError());
        }
```

//--- below is how i do connect to openfire  .

```
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
        config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);



        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        // Connect to the server
        connection.connect();
        // Log into the server
        connection.login("test", "test","testresource");
```

i attached the xmpp xml that i received from log

sending....

```
<stream:stream to="localhost" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<stream:stream to="xuser" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<auth mechanism="DIGEST-MD5" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"></auth>
<response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">Y2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCx1c2VybmFtZT0idGVzdCIscmVhbG09InpoYW5nIixub25jZT0ieHZacDFOdHlkcld6MVBzOFA0UGlnbWgrbHRieWtyclNYU0NLWVJaRyIsbmM9MDAwMDAwMDEsY25vbmNlPSIxdThheGtJSWgrSzhBLzFBSDRtTHJ5OUxDTE1OSFpBa0xvdlVGcVFGIixkaWdlc3QtdXJpPSJ4bXBwL3poYW5nIixtYXhidWY9NjU1MzYscmVzcG9uc2U9MGE3YzEzOWRkODliZjk5NDcxN2ZiNjQzY2E5NWM3ZDUscW9wPWF1dGgsYXV0aHppZD0idGVzdCI=</response>
<stream:stream to="xuser" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<iq id="CHWuJ-0" type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>god</resource></bind></iq>
<iq id="CHWuJ-1" type="set"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
<compress xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/compress'>
<method>zlib</method></compress>
<stream:stream to="xuser" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<iq id="CHWuJ-2" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"></query></iq>
<presence id="CHWuJ-3"></presence>
<iq id="CHWuJ-4" to="pubsub.my.openfire.server" type="set"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><create node='TestNode2323'/><configure><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="pubsub#persist_items" type="boolean"><value>0</value></field><field var="pubsub#deliver_payloads" type="boolean"><value>1</value></field><field var="pubsub#access_model" type="list-single"><value>open</value></field></x></configure></pubsub></iq>
```

receive....

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="xuser" id="d0689fdf" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls>
<mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>
zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features><proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="xuser" id="d0689fdf" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
<mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression>
<auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register"/></stream:features>
<challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
cmVhbG09InpoYW5nIixub25jZT0ieHZacDFOdHlkcld6MVBzOFA0UGlnbWgrbHRieWtyclNYU0NLWVJaRyIscW9wPSJhdXRoIixjaGFyc2V0PSJ1dGYtOCIsYWxnb3JpdGhtPSJtZDUtc2VzcyI=</challenge>
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
cnNwYXV0aD1jOWIyOWIxYTMwN2Q5ZjdkYmZiOGM4MDBkMTU4OWFmZQ==</success>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="xuser" id="d0689fdf" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
<iq type="result" id="CHWuJ-0" to="xuser/d0689fdf"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>test@xuser/god</jid></bind></iq>
<iq type="result" id="CHWuJ-1" to="test@xuser/god"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
<compressed xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/compress'/>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="xuser" id="d0689fdf" xml:lang="en" version="1.0"><stream:features><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
<iq type="result" id="CHWuJ-2" to="test@xuser/god"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="test" name="test" subscription="none"/></query></iq>
<iq type="error" id="CHWuJ-4" to="test@xuser/god" from="pubsub.my.openfire.server"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><create node="TestNode2323"/><configure><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="pubsub#persist_items" type="boolean"><value>0</value></field><field var="pubsub#deliver_payloads" type="boolean"><value>1</value></field><field var="pubsub#access_model" type="list-single"><value>open</value></field></x></configure></pubsub><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Intepreted..

```
<iq id="CHWuJ-0" to="xuser/d0689fdf" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>test@xuser/god</jid></bind></iq>
<iq id="CHWuJ-1" to="test@xuser/god" type="result"></iq>
<iq id="CHWuJ-2" to="test@xuser/god" type="result"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="test" name="test" subscription="none"></item></query></iq>
<iq id="CHWuJ-4" to="test@xuser/god" from="pubsub.my.openfire.server" type="error"><pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><create node='TestNode2323'/><configure xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"><value>0</value></configure></pubsub><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is generated by the server (see [XMPPError](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/XMPPError.html)). I tried myself to get the exact same error code, but failed. However, I have the feeling that this is a misconfiguration of the server. Did you try connecting with another client, e.g. using your favorite Jabber client?

You could also try to enable Smacks XMPP debugging feature and post the messages that caused the error:

```
static {
    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
}
```

(You may also want to add smackx-debug.jar to get even more debugging features)

Comment: So it's obviously not a authentication but a pubsub problem. So you've been able to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem that I just recently solved.

I have an Openfire server running on my local computer, and I'm using the Smack API to communicate with the server. In Openfire, I defined two users: sender, and receiver. I did not use email addresses for usernames.

In my code I have a connection for "sender" on one thread, and a connection for "receiver" on a separate thread. Initially, when sending messages, I received `remote-server-not-found(404)` error responses from the Openfire server. I found that, when creating the chat request by the sender, I needed to set the participant as `receiver@[Openfire domain]`.

So if your Openfire domain is *foo*, it would be `receiver@foo`. Obviously, this is not the email address of the "receiver" user. Typically, the domain is really just the name of the machine on which the Openfire server is running.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am not able to get it resolved. I have used gaurav@abc.com, but I am not able to resolve it. Can You please help me

Comment: How come this is not marked as the right answer? It solved my problem too

Answer (score 2):

please check if the packet is sent to the right user!

You should set a valid JID for the "to" attribute of the iq packet, so the server can send the packet to the receiver.
I got this error before because I set the wrong JID to the packet.

btw, you can add XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true in your code to see what you sent or look the error log in openfire web console, and you may find some error like this:
Error trying to connect to remote server: theWrongHost(DNS lookup: theWrongHost:5269)